# How do I use the values of toggle buttons to determine which form is opened in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm attempting to use the values of 2 toggle buttons to determine what form to open next.

At the moment I have just the one form developed but the combination of the 2 buttons will result in many more.  I also want to state if an invalid combination has been selected.

Below is where I got to with the code:

```
Public Function Select_Form()

Dim PolForm As Integer
Dim SchAction As Integer

PolForm = Forms("Home").Toggle39.OptionValue
SchAction = Forms("Home").Toggle47.OptionValue

If PolForm = 1 And SchAction = 1 Then DoCmd.OpenForm ("Create New Schedule") 
Else MsgBox ("Please select a valid combination of Policy Form and Action")

End Function
```

This currently opens the form regardless of which toggle buttons are selected.

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Thanks,
Chas

Comment: I don't think this will be clear to many, at least not me. At best, it sounds like a too convoluted user interface.

Comment: Hi Gustav,  thank you for replying.  I'm sure this is a convoluted user interface but equally I believe what I'm looking to achieve here is very simple.  If I can try to put it another way... I'm looking to open a form based upon a selected (toggle) button in each of 2 option groups.  Does that make anymore sense?

Comment: Sounds like simple logic. _If one option_ and (not) _if another option_ then open some form. And so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option value for a toggle button doesn't change, you set it to a value that you want and that value is then passed to the value of the option group frame when the specific toggle button is selected.

i.e. If Toggle39 and Toggle47 are in the same option group, the value of the option group will be the option value of the toggle button that is selected.

I'm assuming these are in different option groups the way you wrote your code so try:

```
PolForm = Forms("Home").OptionGroup1.Value
SchAction = Forms("Home").OptionGroup2.Value
```

Where OptionGroup1 and OptionGroup2 is the name of the group frames you put the toggle buttons in.

Update: Expanded on original answer.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey.  That was exactly what I needed.